# How to merge two query results joining same date

Tags: sql, sql-server

let's say there's a table have data like below

| id | status | date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 4 | 2022-05 |
| 2 | 3 | 2022-06 |

I want find count of id of each month by their status. Something like this below

| date | count(status1) = 4 | count(status2) =3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-05 | 1 | null |
| 2022-06 | null | 1 |

I tried doing

```sql
-- select distinct (not working)

select date, status1, status2 from 
(select date, count(id) as "status1" from myTable
where status = 4 group by date) as myTable1
join
(select date, count(id) as "status2" from myTable
where status = 3 group by date) as myTable2
on myTable1.date = myTable2.date;

-- group by (not working)
```

but it does duplicate the data needed.
and I am using SQL Server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select d.date,
 sum
 (
    case 
      when d.status=4 then 1
      else 0
    end
 )count_status_4,
 sum
 (
    case 
      when d.status=5 then 1
      else 0
    end
 )count_status_5
from your_table as d
group by d.date
```